# Reinitialize a directive on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using the [multi select directive](https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select) for angular. After I have selected some values from the button, the button label gets updated to reflect the change. I want to refresh/reinitialize the directive on a button click without refreshing the page so that button goes back to the original state. Please find the link for plunker below.

Punker: http://plnkr.co/edit/52kgSkn0V3qwH4NkAAad?p=preview

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="isteven-multi-select.css" />
    <script src="isteven-multi-select.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main" >
    <div>
      <div isteven-multi-select
        max-labels="2" 
        input-model="plugins" 
        output-model="chosenPlugins" 
        button-label="name" 
        item-label="name" 
        tick-property="selected">
      </div>
      <div>
        Plugins: {{ chosenPlugins }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button ng-click="resetDirective()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `clearClicked()` in place of `resetDirective()`? Taking a brief look at the source code for that directive indicates that probably does what you want.

Comment: Typically, a properly implemented custom input control uses `ng-model` and setting `ng-model` drives the selection of the direction. This one decided to use `input-model`, but resetting the `input-model` to `[]` does not work until select clicked again. You should follow up with the developer on how he intended to make it work, if that is at all supported

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about functionality of a little-known custom control - not a general AngularJS question

Comment: Same thing here. An Angular plugin that has an input model and an output model can't be considered as regular Angular code.